# Variables are not available after delete twice in a for loop (linked list)

Tags: c++

```
class LN {
  public:
    LN ()                        : next(nullptr){}
    LN (const LN<T>& ln)         : value(ln.value), next(ln.next){}
    LN (T v, LN<T>* n = nullptr) : value(v), next(n){}
    T      value;
    LN<T>* next;
};

void remove(LN<T>*& l) {
    if (l == nullptr)
        return;
    for (LN<T>* p = l; p->next != nullptr; p = p->next)
    {
        if (p -> value == p -> next -> value)
        {
            LN<T>* to_delete = p;
            p = p -> next;
            delete to_delete;

            LN<T>* to_delete2 = p;
            p = p->next;
            delete to_delete2;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to write a function that will delete the duplicate pair in a linked list.

For example 1 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> nullptr should be 2 -> 3 -> nullptr after calling the function (removing the both value if they are duplicate)

I went through the debug line by line and I could not find what is wrong. In the debug, it just showed "variables are not available".

Can someone help me to fix it? many thanks.

Comment: There's a node whose `next` used to point to `to_delete`, and now points to random garbage. Or, if the two nodes being deleted are at the beginning of the list, `l` now points to random garbage.

Comment: The test case does include that two nodes are the same at the beginning of the list.  Any suggestion how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

In `remove` method, you should check whether two very first node has same value. May be like that

```
template <typename T>
void remove(LN<T>*& head)
{
    LN<T>* tmp1, *tmp2, *duplicate;
    tmp1 = head;
    while (tmp1 != nullptr && tmp1->next != nullptr)
    {
        tmp2 = tmp1;
        while (tmp2->next != NULL)
        {
            if (tmp1->value == tmp2->next->value)
            {
                duplicate = tmp2->next;
                tmp2->next = tmp2->next->next;
                delete(duplicate);
            }
            else 
                tmp2 = tmp2->next;
        }
        tmp1 = tmp1->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, your fix works only if the first two value are the same. But it does not work when the duplicates are in the middle.

Comment: Sr for my bad, you should try block of code which is updated

Comment: Hey thanks for the update, but there is still a problem. Your code only removes duplicate value. It needs to remove both the duplicate value and the original value.  1 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> nullptr should be  2 -> 3 -> nullptr  (both 1 are removed)

Comment: In that case, i think you simply add an vector stored value which is duplicate, then delete and reassign after `remove` function

Comment: Hi, I have tried it, I push_back every duplicate value in to the vector, and I added another for loop to loop through the list. but I met the same problem when I delete the node. It shows "variables are not available". Your previous code kind of worked, but it only works when the first two values are the same.